# Ubuntu 19.10 Dual Monitor Intel Graphics Display Issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, intel

I have a Fujitsu Laptop with a Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) internal graphics card.  My graphics on my main display are great.  I don't have any issue there.  My graphics on my Dell external monitor are problematic.  They have illuminated pixels throughout the image on most of the display. What I am referring to is pixels that are lit up that are not in the picture itself.  Hopefully the attached photo will help.

I upgraded my display drivers to the newest versions found on https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/stack.  I have since rebooted since I updated things as well.

I tested the monitors display with a different Windows based laptop and the display is working perfectly fine...

Please let me know if you would like me to run any commands and which ones to run.  Any advice is appreciated!  Thanks!

[Pixelated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ9yP.jpg)

Comment: 19.10 is still in beta and is off topic here I suggest you try 19.04

Comment: Thank you!  I may roll back to 19.04.  I was hoping maybe their might be a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's 'snow', AKA static. Please try these mechanical solutions:

1. Re-route the cable to get it away from power cables and transformers.
2. Put the monitor in a different position with respect to the laptop.
3. Try another cable to the external monitor.
4. Try a different monitor.
5. Boot with a Ubuntu LiveUSB on the Windows laptop.

Comment: It does appear as "snow", static.  The crazy thing is that the whites on certain applications are perfectly fine.  I believe it might be an issue in the Beta release.  

I have tried:

A new HDMI cable
Cable routing is not near any transformers or other potential static.

I'll test a different monitor tomorrow and see.  

Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Gill TY for trying #1 and #3 above. Hope it does not require #5, but with interim releases...